# Invoking anonymous functions

Tags: java

I know how the following JavaScript example works:

```
(function(params){statements();}) ();
```

I don't know, if there is an equivalent in Java, because I don't use Java.
But one of my friends ask me for the meaning of the following Java example:

```
(something, function(params){statements();}) ();
```

I don't know, if this code snippet works.
If this is a valid example, what does *something* mean? Is it a variable and does *something* have a specific type? Does *something* set the value for *this* within the called function or is it simply some kind of parameter?

Comment: No, that is not a valid Java example.

Comment: The compiler will kill you if you try to do something like that.

Comment: Step 1: Come up with an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/). Step 2: Try to compile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like *functions* in Java. It's called *methods*.

---

In Java, there are **no** anonymous methods. There is something similar, called [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), but it's executed just once and cannot be reffered and/or instantiated.

For example:

```
public interface SayHello() {
    public void sayHello();
}

public class MisterV {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SayHello hello = new SayHello() {
           public void sayHello() {
               System.out.println("Hello World");
           }
        };

        hello.sayHello();
    }
}
```

The `sayHello()` method will be executed just once and will print:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Funny thing is that Java 8 still doesn't have anonymous methods, what you see is just a shortcut for one-method anonymous class :)

Comment: Thanks, will note that.

Answer (score 2):

Java and JavaScript has zero relations to each other.

Comment: It's okay I just wanted you to avoid thinking any parallelism or relations between the two language. Of course in general you can achive the same things, but that applies to any two general purpose language.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid Java code. Java doesn't have anonymous functions, it only has anonymous classes.